# How could I stream a video torrent on windows universal?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, streaming, bittorrent, torrent

I'm currently developing a popcorn-time like app for Windows 8.1/WP8.1, and I would like to know how I could possibly stream a torrent file? How complex would it be to get a video stream, starting with what I have available in this API: https://yts.to/api/ (aka, a magnet link and a list of trackers)?

Comment: First of all, what bit torrent lib are you using?

Comment: None for the moment, but I'm guessing I could use This: https://github.com/mono/monotorrent

Comment: Yes. The only two torrent apps that exist in windows [phone] store used monotorrent, but the developers took some months only to make this library work because you will have to update a lot of functions and upgrade to new apis.

Comment: My advice is that you do this first, get the basics done (read torrent, download it, ...) and only after this start looking on video streaming. Open source it would be cool, monotorrent is outdated and inactive.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Well for the moment, I'm implementing the yts.to API, to get a fully functional app. Except that "Watch" button :/

Comment: Got it. What will you do relating to legal stuff?

Comment: Legal-wise, I'il put a massive disclaimer when the App starts, saying that "Downloading potentially copyrighted torrents may be illegal in your territory, please document yourself before using this App". Anyway, Microsoft is rather cool with slightly shady Apps. There are already a few That stream via web hosters (1Box). Except That their catalog is rather limited and these Apps are generally full of ads, or have a bad UI or UX.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, Popcorn Time is a bittorrent client (like utorrent) with video player support.

You will have to implement the bittorrent protocol or get an existent lib (monotorrent, ...) to work.

You will need to:

1. Read torrent file (or magnet)
2. Connect with trackers
3. Get a list of peers
4. Connect with peers
5. Download and upload pieces

To stream, I believe it basically means that the torrent should be downloaded sequentially.

Be careful with legal stuff.